# Wordpress problem with htmlentities

Tags: javascript, encoding

I make some changes over the post before storing it in the database.

I use `content_save_pre` to do this.

Some characters like `"` get done into `&#8220;` in the JavaSript code which I insert (part of the change). How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the code you're inserting? The function `wptexturize()` is doing this on the fly at runtime, so knowing the structure is important for figuring out how to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "convert_chars" filter is causing the trouble, try removing it by:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars' );
```

Also try removing the richedit_pre hook (which formats the text for the rich text editor, also uses convert_chars function) by:

```
remove_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'wp_richedit_pre' );
```

Hope that helps!